# Virtualmin clean install - Internal Server errors with PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, suexec

I've just reinstalled my server's OS (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) and installed Virtualmin using the install script (install.sh). Everything on the server is completely vanilla - the only thing I've done after logging into the clean system is to run install.sh and enable the userdir Apache module.

I've created a virtual host and logged into its account using SFTP, then created a php file with phpinfo() in it. When I browse to the file I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Virtualmin's default settings use fcgid for executing PHP.

Apache's error.log shows this:

```
[Fri Jan 27 10:20:46 2012] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /home/username/public_html/info.php with wrapper /home/username/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi
suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Fri Jan 27 10:20:52 2012] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /home/username/public_html/info.php(28890) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 112
```

and suexec.log has this:

```
[2012-01-27 10:20:46]: uid: (1000/username) gid: (1000/username) cmd: php5.fcgi
[2012-01-27 10:20:46]: cannot get docroot information (/home/username)
```

and the virtual host's error_log has this:

```
[Fri Jan 27 11:07:02 2012] [warn] [client 1.2.3.4] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Fri Jan 27 11:07:02 2012] [error] [client 1.2.3.4] Premature end of script headers: info.php
```

Obviously the problem is with suexec, but I've been playing about with this server for a few days trying to get the config right (and having little success) and this time I'm going to seek help before I touch anything and potentially make it worse :)

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that the apache2-suexec-custom module is installed.
Also, please check the contents of the /etc/apache2/suexec/www-data file:

```
/home
public_html/cgi-bin
# The first two lines contain the suexec document root and the suexec userdir
# suffix. If one of them is disabled by prepending a # character, suexec will
# refuse the corresponding type of request.
# This config file is only used by the apache2-suexec-custom package. See the
# suexec man page included in the package for more details.
```

I suppose you are hosting the sites in the /home directory? If not, you would need to adjust the configuration.